# How to Activate the pervious active Window in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a windows form app using visual studio to capture the screen shot of an active window application. I created a capture button which captures the form itself and not the Previous active window. Thus i want to toggle to the previous active window and a screen shoot should be captured considering that as the current active window. I am relatively new to VB. kindly help me out with this issue.

thank you.

Comment: Can you post some code that you already wrote and show which problem you are facing to!

Comment: It would be good if you could post some code. But one way to do it would be to constantly keep track of the active window handle in a global variable...using a timer, etc. Every time the active window changes, as long as it's not your form handle, set that to the global variable. Then in your button code, use the global variable handle to switch to that window and capture it.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to prevent your Form from getting Focus, thus keeping the "previous" form as the active selected one.

See [WS_EX_NOACTIVATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx):

> A top-level window created with this style does not become the
>   foreground window when the user clicks it.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Structure RECT
        Public Left As Integer
        Public Top As Integer
        Public Right As Integer
        Public Bottom As Integer
    End Structure

    Private Const WM_MOVING As Integer = &H216
    Private Const WS_EX_NOACTIVATE As Integer = &H8000000

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or WS_EX_NOACTIVATE
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        If m.Msg = WM_MOVING Then
            Dim r As RECT = DirectCast(Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, GetType(RECT)), RECT)
            Me.Location = New Point(r.Left, r.Top)
        End If

        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Console.WriteLine("...your active screen capture code here...")
    End Sub

End Class
```